# My function does not return a variable and i dont know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sqlite

i´m trying to make function and then call it, but one of the functions does not working. It does not returns variable. My code is separated to 2 files, library named libar2 and the program.
The function sort does not returning anything. The error is: NameError: name 'to_write' is not defined. It should be a dictionary.

This is the program:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
#List indexu
indexus = ["Č.refer.dokladu", "Číslo dokladu", "Řádka ref.dok.","Účetní řádka"]
#List všech sloupců
listus = ["TypRefDokl","Č.refer.dokladu","Číslo dokladu","Řádka ref.dok.", "Účetní řádka","ÚčOkOdesíl", "Obchodní proces", "Logický systém", "Prodejní organizace", "Ledger", "Nositel nákladů", "Klíč měny účet.okruhu", "Prodej.doklad", "Druh pohybu MM", "Fiskální rok", "Druh faktury", "V měně profit centra", "Ref.org.jednotka", "Typ ukazatele", "Skupina původu", "Označení nemovitosti", "Podčíslo", "Druh dokladu", "Množství", "Refer.fiskální rok", "Druh výkonu", "ÚčOk příjemce", "Obor", "Cesta odbytu", "Čas pořízení dat", "Datum dokl.", "Elimin.profit center", "Partner.PrCtr", "Referenční operace", "Objekt původu", "Provoz.ekon.operace", "Zakázka odběratele", "Klíč firemní měny PrCtr", "Pol.zakázky odběr.", "Č.postupu k operacím", "Klíč měny trans.", "Verze", "Investiční majetek", "Odbytový doklad", "Dokl.byl stornován", "Text", "TypDokl", "Závod", "Třída objektu", "Datum účtování", "Nákladový okruh", "Polož.nák.dokladu", "Okruh ocenění", "Číslo reprezentativ.materiálu", "Pol.odbyt.dokladu", "Druh pohybu", "Verze rozlišení", "Druh ocenění", "Pol.prod.dokladu", "Datum pořízení", "Oblast hosp.výsl.", "V měně transakce", "Druh záznamu", "Prodejní kancelář", "Dodavatel", "Statist.ukazatel", "Odpisová oblast", "Partner.společnost", "Číslo účtu", "Klíč nemovitostí", "Zakázka", "Odběratel", "Znak Má dáti/Dal", "Dokl.je stornov.dokl.", "Nákupní doklad", "Skupina prodeje", "Druh dokl.", "Nákl.středisko", "Automatický znak", "Funkční obl.partnera", "Účetní období", "Funkční oblast", "Prvek SPP", "Materiál", "Datum valuty", "Dr.pohybu na IM", "Pracovní úsek", "Oper.ref.dokl.", "Profit centrum", "V měně účetního okruhu", "Dr.objektu příjemce", "Text účtů", "Jméno uživatele", "Zákl.měrná jednotka"]
columnnames = []
from Libar2 import (premade_table, sort, write, find_unknown)
import openpyxl
from json import load
import sqlite3
with open("cfg.json","r") as cfgfile:
    cfg = load(cfgfile)
dodavatele = cfg["DODAVATELE"]
con = sqlite3.connect("rozpocet.db")
cur = con.cursor()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(cfg["XLSX_FILE"])
sheet = wb.active

premade_table(cur)

loaded_sql = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM {0}".format(cfg["DB_NAME"]))

sort(indexus,loaded_sql,sheet)

write(cur,to_write,listus)

cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(
    cislo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    JmenoDodavatele TEXT)'''.format(cfg["TAB_SUPLY"]))

find_unknown(dodavatele,cfg["DB_NAME"],cur) 
        
cur.execute(
        """CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS v1 AS 
        SELECT {1}.JmenoDodavatele,{0}.text,{0}.[Číslo účtu],{0}.[Text účtů],{0}.[Účetní období],{0}.[V měně profit centra] FROM {0} 
        LEFT JOIN {1} ON {0}.dodavatel = {1}.cislo;""".format(cfg["DB_NAME"], cfg["TAB_SUPLY"]))

        
con.commit()
```

And this is the Library:

```
def premade_table(cur):
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {0}(
    {1} INTEGER NOT NULL,
    {2} INTEGER NOT NULL,
    {3} INTEGER NOT NULL,     
    {4} INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ({1},{2},{3},{4})
    )""".format("db1", "[Č.refer.dokladu]", "[Číslo dokladu]",
                "[Řádka ref.dok.]","[Účetní řádka]"))
    listus = listus = ["TypRefDokl","Č.refer.dokladu","Číslo dokladu","Řádka ref.dok.", "Účetní řádka","ÚčOkOdesíl", "Obchodní proces", "Logický systém", "Prodejní organizace", "Ledger", "Nositel nákladů", "Klíč měny účet.okruhu", "Prodej.doklad", "Druh pohybu MM", "Fiskální rok", "Druh faktury", "V měně profit centra", "Ref.org.jednotka", "Typ ukazatele", "Skupina původu", "Označení nemovitosti", "Podčíslo", "Druh dokladu", "Množství", "Refer.fiskální rok", "Druh výkonu", "ÚčOk příjemce", "Obor", "Cesta odbytu", "Čas pořízení dat", "Datum dokl.", "Elimin.profit center", "Partner.PrCtr", "Referenční operace", "Objekt původu", "Provoz.ekon.operace", "Zakázka odběratele", "Klíč firemní měny PrCtr", "Pol.zakázky odběr.", "Č.postupu k operacím", "Klíč měny trans.", "Verze", "Investiční majetek", "Odbytový doklad", "Dokl.byl stornován", "Text", "TypDokl", "Závod", "Třída objektu", "Datum účtování", "Nákladový okruh", "Polož.nák.dokladu", "Okruh ocenění", "Číslo reprezentativ.materiálu", "Pol.odbyt.dokladu", "Druh pohybu", "Verze rozlišení", "Druh ocenění", "Pol.prod.dokladu", "Datum pořízení", "Oblast hosp.výsl.", "V měně transakce", "Druh záznamu", "Prodejní kancelář", "Dodavatel", "Statist.ukazatel", "Odpisová oblast", "Partner.společnost", "Číslo účtu", "Klíč nemovitostí", "Zakázka", "Odběratel", "Znak Má dáti/Dal", "Dokl.je stornov.dokl.", "Nákupní doklad", "Skupina prodeje", "Druh dokl.", "Nákl.středisko", "Automatický znak", "Funkční obl.partnera", "Účetní období", "Funkční oblast", "Prvek SPP", "Materiál", "Datum valuty", "Dr.pohybu na IM", "Pracovní úsek", "Oper.ref.dokl.", "Profit centrum", "V měně účetního okruhu", "Dr.objektu příjemce", "Text účtů", "Jméno uživatele", "Zákl.měrná jednotka"]
    columnnames = []
    for line in listus:
        if line in cur.execute('SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO("{}")'.format("db1")):
            pass
        else:
            columnnames.append(line)
    
    for line in columnnames:
        try:
            cur.execute("ALTER TABLE db1 ADD [{0}]".format(line))
        except:
            pass

    return columnnames


def sort(indexus,loaded_sql,sheet):
    ii = 0
    sqldic = {}
    for line in loaded_sql:
        if ii == 0:
            col = line
            ii += 1
            index_sql = [col.index(j) for j in indexus]
        sqldic["".join(str(line[i]) for i in index_sql)] = line
    
    ii = 0
    exceldic = {}
    for line in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
        if ii == 0:
            col = line
            ii += 1
            index = [col.index(j) for j in indexus]
        exceldic["".join(line[i] for i in index)] = line
    
    
    to_write = {}
    for key in exceldic.keys():
        if key not in sqldic:
            to_write[key] = exceldic[key]
    return to_write

def write(cur,to_write,listus):
    for key,line in to_write.items():
        a = "("+"?,"*(len(line)-1) + "?)"
        col = "({})".format(",".join([("[{}]".format(i)) for i in listus]))
        ins_val = []
        [ins_val.append(str(i)) for i in line]
        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO db1 {0} VALUES {1}".format(col, a), ins_val)
        except:
            continue

def find_unknown(dodavatele, db_name, cur):
    strsql = 'SELECT dodavatel FROM {}'.format(db_name)
    all_sup = set(str(int(i[0])) for i in cur.execute(strsql) if i[0])
    sup_dif = [x for x in list(all_sup.difference(set(dodavatele.keys())))]
    return sup_dif
```

Comment: use a debugger... you shadow the `to_write` dictionary with the parameter of the functions and is a mess... hint: change name of the parameter of the functions

Comment: ... or simply because you didn't defined it in the 1st program...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main program you have a line

```
write(cur, to_write, listus)
```

but there is no `to_write` variable defined there. I think you indended this to be:

```
to_write = sort(indexus, loaded_sql, sheet)
write(cur, to_write, listus)
```

As a side note, per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) all imports should at the top of the file. Otherwise the code is difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your code, your error should be from the first file at line `write(cur,to_write,listus)`. Because in your first file, you did not defined any variable `to_write` in order to call `write()` function.
Your `to_write` variable in second file is inner-varible which is not defined in global scope, which mean you cannot use it as global variable. Your `sort()` function is returning `to_write` value, so you should pass the returned value of `sort()` function into argument of `write()` function, for example in first file:
In stead of calling them separatively:

```
sort(indexus,loaded_sql,sheet)
write(cur,to_write,listus)
```

You should define and pass it the returned value:

```
to_write = sort(indexus,loaded_sql,sheet)
write(cur,to_write,listus)
```

or for quick:

```
write(cur,sort(indexus,loaded_sql,sheet),listus)
```